# Multi indexing line plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, multi-index

After slicing, I have a multi header Dataframe with two levels, indexed by date, obtained like this:

```
    df = df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_level_values(1).isin({'a','b'})]    


     Date      one                 two                    
                a         b         a         b         
      2         2         3         3         3          
      3         2         3         3         3
      4         2         3         3         3
      5         2         3         3         3
      6         2         3         3         3
      7         2         3         3         3
```

What I would like to do is to plot this Dataframe with a line plot with the Date in axis, the same color for the level 0 and solid/dashed lines for the first level.

I have tried unstacking ie.

```
     df.unstack(level=0).plot(kind='line')
```

but with no success. The plot as it is now, shows Date in x axis but treat each combination of level 0 and 1 headers as a new entry.

Here is a picture of the plot obtained:
 [image: Picture of the plot obtained]

What we would like to implement would be a two levels legend (color/shape of line).

Code Example:

```
  import numpy as np
  import pandas as pd
  A = np.random.rand(4,4)
  C = pd.DataFrame(A, index=range(4), columns=[np.array(['A','A','B','B']), np.array(['a','b','a','b'])])
  C.plot(kind='line')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sure, I have just edited the post to show an example. Here, you will have four different entries (4 colours). While, what I would like is a differentiation between each level.